# Why is this query wrong?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, ms-access

What's wrong with this query? I've tried to run it many times, but [THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZoE2f.png) is what it says.

```
cmd = New OleDbCommand("UPDATE [login] SET nama=?, password=? WHERE idpegawai= '" & idpegumumloker & "'", conn)
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Why do you not use a parameter for the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: Also, please include your error message as text, not an image.

Comment: How do you think ADO.net is supposed to provide values for the question marks (?)?

Comment: @Mary base on pic, the error is second query, the first one is work as well. i use OLEDB

Comment: Do you know why we use parameters in sql statements? What makes you think that it's OK to use parameters only for some parts of the query? Don't you think SQL Injection can occur in the where clause as well?

Comment: There are other issues but the most likely cause of the immediate error is "password" being a reserved word. Wrap it in brackets as you have done for "login" and you should get past that specific issue.

Comment: By the way, why is this question tagged MySQL and Access?

Comment: @jmcilhinney yes! it's work. Thank you Sir ! i tagged it both because i'm learning on MySQL quer and Access query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, there is only one query. I think the line you are referring to is the execution of the command and the problem is this query. Do not post pictures of code on SO.

```
cmd = New OleDbCommand("UPDATE [login] SET nama= @name, [password]= @password WHERE idpegawai= @id", conn)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", TextBox9.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBox12.Text)
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", idpegumumloker)
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: That doesn't fix the syntax error. The comment by jmcilhinney has the solution.

Comment: Thank you to @ jmcilhinney for the correction. I edited my answer accordingly.